# SoundCloud API Not Displaying Proper Play Counts

Tags: soundcloud

I've noticed that for several SoundCloud users, the playback_count value returned from the /tracks API endpoint does not reflect the proper play count value as shown on the user's soundcloud.com profile. An example of this is Opia's track "Falling" (https://soundcloud.com/opia-official/falling). The returned value from the API is: "playback_count: 789730" while the soundcloud.com page I linked shows 936,413 plays at the time of this post. Is this something that i'm doing wrong on my end? I've tested the api on a bunch of different browsers, different computers, in incognito mode, etc., and still get the same issue.

UPDATE 2/7/2017: both the /tracks/{id} and /users/{id}/tracks endpoint now reflect the correct playback_count value.

Comment: I have observed this problem too.  As far as I can see, there's no official answer yet.

Comment: I've had this problem for quite a while, too, but I just realized it seems to have vanished. API track count and Soundcloud website numbers match now. Maybe you wanna check back.

Comment: For anyone watching this post: both the /tracks/{id} and /users/{id}/tracks endpoint now reflect the correct playback_count value.